# Sitecore ProcessMediaRequest is giving 404 for restricted media

Tags: sitecore-api, media-library

I recently had a requirement to restrict secure media items to download so that only certain logged in users could download them. So to achieve that I have remove read access from the extranet\anonymous user and grant read access to the specific roles. It was working before but not anymore.

When I enter the URL e.g. `local-mywebsite/.../testPDF.ashx`

It redirects to login page and after successful login the pdf should be downloaded.

But login is successful and after that `DoProcessRequest` is returning 404 (return `base.DoProcessRequest(context)`) for the restricted media file.

Can anyone assist me what is going wrong?

Sitecore version - Sitecore 8.1 (rev. 160519)

Here is my code-

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Foundation.Framework.Sitecore.Sites;
using Glass.Mapper;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Resources.Media;
using Context = Sitecore.Context;

namespace MyProject.Shared.Handlers
{
    public class MediaRequestHandler : Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler
    {
        public const string ImageAcceptTypePrefix = "image/";
        
        private readonly IEnumerable<string> _allowedSiteNames = new[]
        {
            RegisteredSites.ABC,
            RegisteredSites.XYZ
        };
        
        private readonly MediaProvider _mediaProvider;
        
        public MediaRequestHandler(MediaProvider mediaProvider)
        {
            _mediaProvider = mediaProvider;
        }
        
        public MediaRequestHandler() : this(new MediaProvider()) { }
        
        public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetAcceptTypes(HttpContext context) => context.Request.AcceptTypes;
        
        public bool ProcessMediaRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (!_allowedSiteNames.Contains(Sitecore.Context.Site.Name) ||
            !GetAcceptTypes(context).Any(type => type.ToLower().StartsWith(ImageAcceptTypePrefix)))
            {
                return base.DoProcessRequest(context);
            }
            
            var mediaRequest = _mediaProvider.ParseMediaRequest(context.Request);
            var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(mediaRequest.MediaUri.MediaPath);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return base.DoProcessRequest(context);
            }
            
            var mediaItem = GetOptimizedMediaItem(item, context.Request.AcceptTypes);
            var media = _mediaProvider.GetMedia(mediaItem);
            
            if (context?.Request.AcceptTypes != null && context.Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("image/webp"))
            {
                mediaRequest.Options.CustomOptions["extension"] = "webp";
            }
            
            return DoProcessRequest(context, mediaRequest, media);
        }
        
        protected override bool DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            return ProcessMediaRequest(context);
        }
        
        private static bool AcceptWebP(HttpContext context)
        {
            return context?.Request.AcceptTypes != null && context.Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("image/webp");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is `Sitecore.Context.Site` after you login?

Comment: Hi Marek,

Sitecore.Context.Site is same after login i.e. "mysitename"

Comment: also one more thing to add...below setting is true in my config
```<setting name="RequestErrors.UseServerSideRedirect">
        <patch:attribute name="value" value="true" />
    </setting>```